# Word for going to a university class but without being enrolled?

Tags: single-word-requests, academia

Not sure if this only happens in my country, but a university student can go to a class without actually being enrolled. The student is either there because he wants to "try" the class first, or because the registration capacity is full.

What's the word for that?

Example:

> Mary wasn't sure whether to take the biology course, so she went to
>   [...] first.

Comment: There’s also a common practice of showing up to a full class in hopes of getting an “add” so that you can fully enroll. I am not aware of a word for that particular situation, though.

Comment: Many years ago, I heard it described (outside of North America) as "sitting in"; for example when PhD students might have been encouraged to attend a class at say masters level or undergrad level for no credit, because it would be useful to them.

Comment: As much as bib's answer is correct, and it has been upvoted the most. I am certain that Avangion's answer was the most helpful and informative answer for a person who is a non native speaker.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA! I'll add that the practice of showing up to a full class in the (frequently fulfilled) hope of getting in is called by my university "special permission." What you do is go to the first class and politely ask the professor for a "special permission number." You can then register online using this number even if this would result in over enrollment. The likelihood of this working out is in inverse proportion to how much additional work the professor will have to do for each additional student. :) Although I can't say if this is common usage, most academic terminology is.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A common term is *[audit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/audit)*

> *North American* - Attend (a class) informally, not for academic credit.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I don't think the word *audit* would be used in this circumstance in the UK. Indeed I find it slightly contrary to the usual understanding of *audit*, and *auditor*. I think we would simply call them a *visitor* if they had been invited. Were they there uninvited they would probably be called a *gate-crasher*.

Comment: In the US, it's a formalized arrangement to audit a class - which implies the entire duration of the class term.  A visitor would likely only sit through a single class period in a single day.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Although the word undoubtedly comes from the Latin *auditus* - a hearing  the usual meaning of *audit* is to check up upon e.g. *a financial audit* (OED sense 2). But I have just noticed the OED sense 1 of *audit* is the following, from the 16th century: *1. gen. A hearing, an audience; esp. a judicial hearing of complaints, a judicial examination. arch.* But it is said to be archaic. That leaves only the financial sense. So where does this use of *audit* come from?

Comment: That may be true, @WS2, but that is also the term used to attend a class that the student has not paid for in the US as this link will describe (from Roosevelt University in Chicago, IL):  http://www.roosevelt.edu/registrar/courses/audit.aspx

Comment: @KristinaLopez Well that sounds as foreign to me as calling a building from which doctors work a *surgery* does to some of your compatriots- see questions *passim* today.

Comment: Totally, @WS2.  I love learning new things about our English-speaking neighbors around the world! :-)

Comment: @ws2 I've heard the term used in that sense during my (British) university days. It was a little unusual, but definitely something I've heard here.

Comment: @Racheet Umm. I've had recent university experience, in retirement, but didn't encounter it. What bothers me slightly is that it introduces a very different sense to the word than that of a financial *audit*. And as a lifelong member of the accountancy profession that slightly troubles me.

Comment: Since audit is from Latin for "to hear," this isn't that specialized a sense. You're listening in on the class without otherwise participating. Such people are called auditors. If you doubt the common currency of this term, Google any university website. I am a university instructor, and students frequently ask me if they can audit my courses, as I have done in the past myself. It is neither new nor unusual.

Comment: Keep in mind that for an Audit in the US, you typically still have to *pay* some part of the course fee to attend.  You can't just 'show up'.

Comment: It depends whether you're matriculated or not. Matriculated students generally don't have to pay.

Comment: @WS2 - In the US the word *Audit* is more commonly used for something else, most often when the government tax authority review our tax returns closely, or when a company has its financial records scrutinized. The first time I heard the word for this purpose, it struck me as odd.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer If I understand you correctly you are saying exactly the same thing as me.

Comment: @WS2 - I agree that it sounded strange at first, that I knew it to mean something else. Then i accepted the other meaning, here.

Comment: The word "audit" is commonly used for just showing up and attending a class, but some universities also have a status of "official auditor", which requires signing up (and probably paying) but not getting official credit (and therefore not being required to do the homework or take the exams).   My impression is that the "just show up" meaning is more common, but my sample size is too small to be confident about that.

Comment: My (recent) experience of an LLM and now teaching one is that students do seem to use the word "audit" in the UK for both meanings that @AndreasBlass mentions. When I attended university in the 1980's I never heard the term even though the practice (a right in Cambridge University) was fairly common. But the lack of special usage may have been because Cambridge University had a different conceptual approach to lectures.

Comment: +1 for "audit" being used in this sense in the UK. It sounded strange to me, but that's definitely what my wife's course organisers call it.

Comment: This still does seem an oddly aggrandized way to describe listening. Anyway, I'm off to audit some music.

Comment: @RobertGrant Don't forget to take your audio equipment.

Comment: @RobertGrant Welcome to academia, where we have to use Latin names for everything in order to exhibit a sufficient level of pretension. Are you going to audit the music in an _audit_ orium?

Answer (score 26):

If a student intends to sit in on a course without registering, this is indeed called *auditing*. Auditing can be formal, in which case it might not even be free and could require arrangement with the university, or it can be informal if the professor agrees to allow it (which they may or may not technically be allowed to do).

> Mary wasn't sure whether to take the biology course for credit, so she decided to audit it instead.

Contrary to the dictionary definition, I once took a course in which auditors were required to do all the reading and assignments, even though they wouldn't receive a grade, because all members of the class were expected to contribute. This sort of auditing was still a formal relationship, and I think it was even indicated on their transcripts. These were matriculated graduate students, however. At the same university (not mine), I myself audited a class by casual arrangement with the professor, though his requirements for participation were rather less onerous.

On top of that, there were also "auditors" from the general public in these courses who paid dearly for the privilege of listening to our discussions but, I understand, were expressly forbidden from actually participating in those discussions themselves—they were auditors in the true sense of the word.

The practice of trying a course out, on the other hand, is usually called *shopping*, and many if not most US universities these days allow for a one or two week "shopping period" at the beginning of each semester, so students can do precisely this. Shopping is not a slang term for it, either, but is what the universities themselves officially call it.

> Mary wasn't sure whether to take the biology course, so she tried it out during the shopping period first.

This is a little bit redundant, since you could just say she tried it out or went to check it out, but I thought you might be interested to know this other common term and that there is a distinction between auditing and shopping. The former implies a commitment to a course despite not receiving a grade, while the latter indicates a trial period.

Comment: You said "sit in on" - I think that would work as an answer too. MW even [explicitly mentions 'class' in the definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sit-in-on), although [Oxford doesn't](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sit#sit__55).

Comment: Sure. I guess it depends on how specific you want to be about the nature of the transaction. Auditing may or may not be a formal arrangement, while shopping is a trial period and sitting in would be the most casual and non-specific way to express it. These may all be relevant to the OP.

Comment: +1 for showing how to use the word in the example phrase, +1 for teaching me "shopping period", +1 for explaining how *auditing* works in the US. Oh... I can only upvote once :(

Comment: I would indeed use "audit" if the student had *officially* requested to join the class, and if it would show up anywhere, even if no grade was being given... but "sit in on" in a less formal capacity, if the student just dropped in and listened to the lectures and that's it.

Comment: @neminem I agree with that usage, too, but in practice the distinction is blurry. Technically, as has been pointed out by me and others, auditing is often (typically?) an official way of taking the class, just not for credit. In practice, however, it doesn't always have to be more official than a student simply asking a professor to, in effect, sit in. "May I audit?" and "May I sit in?" are used interchangeably, correct or not. However, I wouldn't use audit in the case of a student sitting in without permission, as would only be possible in a larger lecture in which attendance is not taken.

Answer (score 5):

> **auditor** - a university student registered for a course without credit and without obligation to do work assigned to the class.

[dictionary.com definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/auditor)

Comment: So..."she went to **audit** first?" Is this a common way of saying it?

Comment: In your version she went to a financial examination (`audit` is an official financial examination). I think it should be "she went to _somewhere_ as an **auditor**.

Comment: I've always heard it as a transitive verb; that is, one with a direct object.

She decided to **audit the class** first.

Comment: A financial audit is a different sense. It's also a noun. Xenophon is correct about this sense being a verb. You could use it intransitively, though, and I think "audit the class first" makes less sense than "try it out" or "observe the first few classes" since auditing isn't the same thing as shopping. So, no, janoChen it isn't common.

Comment: @Avangion 'audit' can be used as either a noun or a verb in either the financial or university sense. When a financial auditor decides to audit you, the event is called an audit. The noun form is less common with the university sense, though it is still used that way at times. For instance, university records clerks would refer to an 'audit' on someone's transcript.

Comment: @reirab You're right, of course. I'm not sure I've heard it used as a noun in the university sense, but it does seem likely in the situation you describe (though in the U.S. we don't refer to staff members as clerks so the cultural difference as always bleeds into the grammatical one—at my university I'm not sure they keep track of auditors at all, at least not in every case).

Comment: @Avangion The terms vary from one university to another. At the university I attended (which was in the U.S.,) the people who worked in the undergraduate records office were indeed officially called 'records clerks.' My mother was one for several years.

Answer (score 4):

This is sometimes known as **shopping**, as in during "shopping period."

If it continues into the semester, if the instructor is aware of the student and the student still submits work (which may or may not actually be graded, due to their enrollment status), this is indeed known as **auditing** as others have said.

If the instructor does not know of the student, I've heard this colloquially called **vagabonding**.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, attending a university session in order to 'try it out' would be considered a

"**Taster Session** (or just a "**Taster**")

> (From [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/taster):)  *4. a sample or preview of a product, experience, etc, intended to stimulate interest in the product, experience, etc,
>   itself: the single serves as a taster for the band's new album.*

You can see it being used by various universities

http://www.london.ac.uk/tasters, and http://www.ucl.ac.uk/prospective-students/widening-participation/activities/taster-courses, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Should suit you, try "*test*".

[**Test** more generally means "**trial**."](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/test)

> - If you test a soap on your skin, you use it on one small patch, to    see if you'll have an allergic reaction.
> - A drug test looks for the presence of drugs in your system.

[test](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/test)
(noun)
1.a procedure intended ***to establish the quality, performance, or reliability*** of something, especially before it is taken into widespread use.

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/test))

Comment: I don't think test is a good word to use in this context. Try is much better. Sometimes, we might colloquially say "test it out" but "try it out" is still better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "Try slash test" as we might pronounce it? Your answer isn't clear to me.

Comment: @MystiSinha, Most native speakers won't use "test", however, I echo Fumble Finger's thought that - it is slightly contrary to the usual understanding of audit, and auditor.